# Cocoa Application - XCode 8 and App Delegate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode8, appdelegate, managedobjectcontext

In XCode 7, I got the managedObjectContext like this:

```
[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]
```

in XCode 8 I get an Error over the ***managedObjectContext*** saying:

> *Instance method 'managedObjectContext' not found;*

How do I get to the App's managedObjectContext ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was:

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

_managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
```

And the problem with with the calling the App Delegate like this:

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you would use something like this:

```
let context = (NSApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```